# Nginx won't serve PHP files from a remote server

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

When I call NGINX server, it should serve php files stored on a remote PHP server. Currently I get `404 Not Found - nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`. If I change `root /srv/www/site` to `root /var/www/html` then it successfully serves `index.html` from NGINX so the request actually never hits PHP server at all.

- PHP SERVER: 192.168.99.31 (`PHP 7.1.15`)
- NGINX SERVR: 192.168.99.32 (`nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`)

PHP server is accessible from NGINX server over port `9000` as seen below so I don't think there is any connection related issues here.

```
vagrant@nginx:~$ nc -zv 192.168.99.31 9000
Connection to 192.168.99.31 9000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

**PHP**

```
vagrant@php:~$ cat /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

[www]
user                   = www-data
group                  = www-data

listen                 = 9000
listen.allowed_clients = 192.168.99.32
listen.owner           = www-data
listen.group           = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children        = 5
pm.start_servers       = 2
pm.min_spare_servers   = 1
pm.max_spare_servers   = 3
```

-

```
vagrant@php:~$ dpkg --list | grep php

ii  php-common                       1:60+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
ii  php7.1                           7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-cgi                       7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-cli                       7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-common                    7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-fpm                       7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-json                      7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-mbstring                  7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-mcrypt                    7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-mysql                     7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-opcache                   7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-readline                  7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
ii  php7.1-zip                       7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
```

-

```
vagrant@php:~$ cat /srv/www/site/index.php 
<?php
echo 'Hello from PHP host'.PHP_EOL;
```

**NGINX**

```
vagrant@nginx:~$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /srv/www/site;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass 192.168.99.31:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
}
```

-

```
vagrant@nginx:~$ cat /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

-

```
vagrant@nginx:~$ cat /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: 404 not found would indicate that the webroot isn't set properly, although it looks OK. Are there any messages in `/var/log/nginx/site_error.log`, the generic nginx error log (usually `/var/log/nginx/error.log`) or in the FPM log? Also, can the www-data user actually access `/srv/www/site`? Is the ownership/permission on this folder correct?

Comment: I am getting `404` just because there is no file under `/var/www/html` of NGINX server. If I put a "index.html", it will display the content nicely. Request actually never goes out from NGINX to PHP server. There must be something else I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SORTED**

So it is all about changing `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`. See cleaned version below.

```
ubuntu@nginx:~$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /srv/www/site;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 192.168.99.31:9000;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the statement:

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
```

Which tests for the existence of the file on the **local machine**. Since you are attempting to execute PHP scripts on some other machine, the `try_files` statement is probably forcing the 404 response.

Either delete the `try_files` statement and rely on the remote machine to check for the existence of script files and handle the [uncontrolled requests](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) exploit correctly.

Or, mirror the installation across both servers.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: I removed the whole block and tried before but nothing changed.